# Neuroshima Hex - Medics

Tags: neuroshima-hex

When playing with the Moloch army, would it ever be advantageous to use the medic tile on another medic tile when playing the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be if you have you base placed in the edge of the board surrounded by your tiles and you want to prevent enemy from gaining access to it.